# scala 2.13 auto implicit resolution error

Tags: scala, scala-collections, implicit, scala-2.13

I am facing this weird problem related to scala implicit resolution

Here is the code snippet

```
import scala.collection.Factory
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq

sealed trait A

sealed trait B

case class BImpl() extends B

case class AImpl() extends A

object implicitsContainer {

  type AB = (A, B)

  implicit def toStringAnyTuples[C[X] <: Iterable[X], A <: AB]
  (col: C[A])
  (implicit factory: Factory[(String, Any), C[(String, Any)]])
  : C[(String, Any)] = {

    factory.fromSpecific(col.iterator.map(f => f._1.toString -> f._2))
  }
}

object Main extends App {

  import implicitsContainer._

  def a(f: Seq[(String, Any)]): Seq[(String, Any)] = f

  val w: Seq[(AImpl, BImpl)] = Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl())

  val x: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(w)

  //    Won't compile
  //    val y: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl()))
}
```

Scala automatically picking up the implicit method

```
implicit def toStringAnyTuples[C[X] <: Iterable[X], A <: AB](col: C[A])
  (implicit factory: Factory[(String, Any), C[(String, Any)]])
  : C[(String, Any)] = {

    factory.fromSpecific(col.iterator.map(f => f._1.toString -> f._2))
  }
```

for this: -

```
  val w: Seq[(AImpl, BImpl)] = Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl())

  val x: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(w)
```

but throws an error for this

```
val y: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl()))
```

and the error is:-

```
Error:(44, 47) type mismatch;
 found   : (AImpl, BImpl)
 required: (String, Any)
    val y: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl()))
```

and one more point, if I remove the type from **w**

```
  val w = Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl())

  val x: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(w)
```

then also this will work fine.
The only error is with

```
val y: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(Seq(AImpl() -> BImpl()))
```

I am using: -

SCALA -> **2.13.3**

SBT -> **1.3.13**

JAVA -> **14**

Comment: What is `"test".av`? You don't define `.av` anywhere.

Comment: Sorry for this I just edited the code again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a symptom of the way inference works in the Scala compiler.
Here is a smaller example that shows the same issue:

```
object Test {
  class C[T](x: T)
  implicit def conv(c: C[Int]): C[String] = ???
  def m(cs: C[String]) = 1
  val ci = new C(1)
  def t1: Int = m(ci)       // OK
  def t2: Int = m(new C(1)) // found: Int, expected: String
}
```

When type-checking `new C(1)`, the compiler pushes down the expected type `String` to type
checking the expression `1`, which fails. In the line above, type checking `ci` with expected type
`C[String]` succeeds thanks to the implicit conversion.
My suggestion here would be to define an extension method that performs the conversion, instead
of making the conversion implicit. This is also recommended for clarity - implicit conversions like
the one defined in your example can lead to surprising, hard to diagnose issues.
In my example, it would look like this:

```
object Test {
  class C[T](x: T)
  implicit class CExt(private val c: C[Int]) extends AnyVal {
    def toCString: C[String] = ???
  }
  def m(cs: C[String]) = 1
  val ci = new C(1)
  def t1: Int = m(ci.toCString)
  def t2: Int = m(new C(1).toCString)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's just type inference issue. Type parameter of `Seq.apply` was not inferred. Try

```
val y: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(Seq[(AImpl, BImpl)](AImpl() -> BImpl()))
```

or

```
val y: Seq[(String, Any)] = a(Seq[(A, B)](AImpl() -> BImpl()))
```

Comment: Is there any way to omit the passing type parameter explicitly? Like for example using another implicit method or by updating the old implicit method?

Comment: @Divyanshu Not sure. Providing hints for compiler (like specifying type parameters explicitly or type ascription) is standard way to improve type inference in Scala when some type is not inferred. Also implicit conversions (on contrary to other usage of implicits) are not recommended.